# How to do verify domain in RESTFul with ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, restful-authentication

Currently, I building my website personal (using ASP.NET MVC 3).

I want to provide some services to public by using API, finished building everything, but RESTFul does not contain on Authorization, I read this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/06/14/how-to-do-api-key-verification-for-rest-services-in-net-4.aspx

But I could not use the method with ASP.NET MVC 3!!

I want the following:

1- Send Api-Keys for those who want to use my service

2- verify Domain (owner api-key == OR != owner domain) !!!! Is this possible?

Comment: "Does current domain that uses api-key really is owner that key?"  Huh?  Could you try editing your question and rephrasing the parts in bold.

Comment: O qes, naze desu ka ? なぜですか？ I'm Japanese, sorry for my bad EN Lang!!

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a requirement that they always send their key in the requests.  Then you could [subclass the AuthorizeAttribute](http://geekswithblogs.net/thomasthedeuce/archive/2009/06/25/133056.aspx) to check if the key in the request matches something in your datastore.  This attribute can then be decorated on your controllers.

You can get the domain making the request using [Request.UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx)

Comment: thanks, any idea about second point in my question above "verify Domain"

Comment: You mean the domain name of another website?

Comment: Yes! When you register in my service  You enter your website in Form after  that, you will get api-key only for your website. How do I know that incoming request from your website not another website? May have stolen your key!!